# svg-sprite-loader how to use https:// svg link data source?

Tags: reactjs, svg, webpack, next.js, svg-sprite-loader

Use case: I am building out a site where the client wants to be able to select and upload their own svg icon for their site.

I have decided to use svg-sprite-loader as a method to reduce overhead on the client side. I am trying to wire up the CMS to the front-end and am running into challenges getting the SVG's to render.

`iconPath`: will return a path as such: **/uploads/this-is-a-file-name.svg**

I am not sure what I am doing wrong to try and implement this?

I have tried using  and it was successful but removes the ability to change the icon color based on its setting.

My current implementation:

```
   <svg>
        <title>{IconCaption}</title>
        <use
          xlinkHref={`http://localhost:1337${iconPath}`}
        />
      </svg>
```